# In MFC CRicheditctrl, how to get the reactangle occupied by the character

Tags: mfc, richedit

In windows OS, in MFC CRichEditctrl, PosFromChar() gives top left position of a character, how to get the height of the character or a rectangle occupied by that character?

Comment: You can use the [GetTextExtent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class?view=vs-2019#gettextextent) function, once you know the character and have retrieved the device context for your control.

Comment: @Adrian, I cannot get the character or text if no text is selected, I can get only char index.

Comment: GetWindowText() will return the entire content of the control, I believe. You can then extract the character at the indicated position.

Answer (score 0):

So - you have a top-left already. Getting a top-left for the next character will get you your top-right.

Now for the bottom. You can use `CRichEditCtrl::LineFromChar` to get your line index. Then use `CRichEditCtrl::LineIndex` to get the character on the next line. That character's top is your bottom.

If there is only one line in your control, you can call cricheditctrl::CharFromPos() repeatedly while incrementing vertical position until it will return the next character. If this is the last char, you can do that for the previous one. If there is only one char in a control - you can temporary add another one, get your coordinates and remove it.

Comment: When we typed only one line and move the cursor or when we move the cursor at the last line, CRichEditCtrl::LineIndex for next line  gives char index as -1. For this scenario what we needs to be done?

Comment: I could not understand your solution for only single line and char at last line. If you provide code snippet it will be helpful

Comment: @user369287 - could you please clarify your requirements and constrains? The most simple way was suggested by Adrian Mole in his comment; you stated that you can't do that without the selection. The common solution to that is to (1) save current selection, (2) hide selection, (3) select the character you are interested in, (4) do your stuff, (5) restore selection, (6) un-hide  selection